# Moving Background stutter/lag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-filters

I'm having trouble getting a website to work properly. It has numerous moving backgrounds and makes use of the css-invert filter.

Please have a look here:

http://epicstudios.de/blackwhite/

My problem is, that even average computers have problems processing the moving background, which is essential for the effect I want the site to have. I figured that the problem might be that I have too many divs with moving backgrounds, but since these Divs have different, inverted background-images, I can't just leave them transparent. Or is there a way to use the invert-filter without giving the div a background-image, so that it inverts the content of the div beneath it? I hope thats clear.

My script for the moving background looks like this:

```
(function($) {  
        var x = 0;  
        var y = 0;  
        var bg = $("body,.overlay,.center_cirlce,.left_circle,.right-circle,.enter,.enter_outer,.enter_inner");  
        bg.css('backgroundPosition', x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');  
        window.setInterval(function() {  
            bg.css("backgroundPosition", -x + 'px' + ' ' + -y + 'px');  
            y++;  
        }, 70);
    })(jQuery);
```

I would like to know, if there is a way to reduce the CPU usage or whatever makes it stutter that awfully, without having to give up the effects I'm aiming for... Or whether I have bad programming somewhere, which I should change to improve performance.

Thank You!

Comment: I think you're asking *a lot* of the browser to achieve this. The images themselves are 2000x3000 pixels. Then there is the invert effect and the overlaid images too, all of which need their transparency calculated for every single frame moved (so multiple times per second). You could possibly optimise it, but with that much going on in the page, I wouldn't be hopeful.

Comment: (Beautiful looking site btw, even if it is stuttery!)

Comment: Use media queries and load different sized (pre scaled) background images, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, animating `background-position` is always a bad idea. Especially on huge images like these. Try to put the background images in their own container and animate that container with `transform: translate()` or even `transform: translate3d()`. It'll be much much smoother.

If you want to do it with JS i can recommend [Greensocks](http://greensock.com/gsap) TweenMax Animation library. It's damn fast and it'll use CSS transforms when available and fall back if not.

And adding `backface-visibility: hidden` to your animated elements will smooth things out too. Problem is, it seems you're using `backface-visiblity` for that effect on your site. To make things perform better I'd advice you rethink your structure and use animations with CSS `transform` as much as possible.